# Automatic generation of the client's login

Tags: magento2

After registering a new account, I would like each customer to receive their individual login name, eg login: Customer:8374233

Does anyone know any extension or how to solve it?

Comment: It means you want to show auto generated name instead of actual name everywhere in the frontend?

Comment: I've found documentation with module im looking for https://magentodeveloper.in/mobile-number-or-username-login-user-guide-magento2.html but I cant see any download link or install via composer on this website... I need this for M 2.4. Maybe you see ?

Comment: for that, you need to contact them.